# Listen for Button Click on Webpage Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an Android WebView that I am using to display a webpage from which I want to listen for the click of a specific button. However, because this webpage is not mine, I cannot insert button.performClick() code into the page's javascript. The button whose click I want to detect is also a div, so its only distinguishing characteristic is its class name. Is it possible to detect when this button is clicked?

Answer (score -1):

Find out weather the website have api services

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?